# Is it possible to play sound(like midi or wave) simultenously using soundpool ?or media?

Tags: android, audio, playback

I'm begginer android programmer and java learner.
I have one team and we have been developing harmony testing application.
Now we have a one problem that we can't play midi files or wave files simultenously.(over two files)
Plz programming masters~~

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to create multiple instances of mediaplayer. Create two different instances of media player and play them simultaneously.

This is the way to play a wave file using mediaplayer:

MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound_file_1);
mp.start();

Comment: play then simultaneously -< how to play them simultaneously? I know to use mediaplayer , but what I want to know is how to play sound simultenously

Comment: You can initialize two media player instance in two different thread. set the audio files for them and then set a timer for start of those two threads simultaneously.. u'll hear both sounds.